# Run a command and email the output, with a subject, using msmtp

Tags: bash, shell-script, msmtp

I have OpenWRT router, installed msmtp. I would like to write a command line (or a .sh file) that would send me the current public IP address, and let Cron execute it every 15 Min.

I found the posting:  [Run a command and email the output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537082/run-a-command-and-email-the-output)

and tried to do the same with msmtp, and it did work: I did the following

> kdig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com | msmtp
> xxxxxxxx@gmail.com

and got an email with the current public IP address, but without a subject, of course, because I didn't set anything. Now, for msmtp, the way to put a subject is

> echo "Subject: Current Public IP" | msmtp xxxxxxx@gmail.com

But I have no idea how I could combine these two things....  I would appreciate your help very much !

Answer (score 0):

I can't claim credit for this approach. I saw it somewhere else but this little snippet could be improved with checking for parameters and adding them in a more flexible manner but it should get the concept across:

```
kdig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com |{
    SUBJ="A Subject"
    echo "From: \"name\"<name@host.com>"
    echo "To: \"me\"<bob@whereever.com>"
    echo "Subject: ${SUBJ}"
    # Now repeat what was piped in 
    cat /dev/fd/0
} | msmtp bob@whereever.com
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the link to the source if possible.

Comment: I tried searching for the original idea - but came up short